# Can I convert my existing flex3/4.5 web application to flash4.5 mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a Flex web application with Java as back end service and now I need to make this web application run on iOS devices. Can I do that? and if so How do I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flash Builder, right-click the project you want to change and select "Add/Change Project Type"

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fed.html#WS933CCB85-8259-496b-8A4E-D0D5B44F6129

For my development, I keep all code in libraries so that my application types are single classes that wrap a view.  You could abstract your application to a library and have multiple application projects.

Or, you could create a mobile application and add a source path to your existing project.

Another approach would be to take your existing application release build SWF and add a descriptor XML to package with adt from the AIR 3.0 SDK:

Download, unpack, and add AIR 3.0 SDK to your path (ex: C:\sdks\AIR\bin).  Make sure a Java JRE is in your path (you can use the one from Flash Builder).  Compile your IPA for iOS:

```
adt -package -target [ipa-test | ipa-debug | ipa-app-store | ipa-ad-hoc]
    -keystore iosPrivateKey.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass qwerty12
    -provisioning-profile ios.mobileprovision
    HelloWorld.ipa
    HelloWorld-app.xml
    HelloWorld.swf icons Default.png
```

Executed via command line, the above will package your SWF and resources to an IPA ready for iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the options I have. Also can you please detail me how I can add the source path to the newly created Mobile Project. A simple example would be great!! Thanks.

Comment: In Flash Builder, right-click project from your Package Explorer and from the context menu select 'Properties'.  Select 'Flex Build Path' from properties dialog, then select 'Source path' tab to 'Add Folder..." and select your existing src folder.